# How to include Office 365 services in my web app

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am absolutely confused with Microsoft's dev center portal, and am going around in loops. I am trying to build a web app for my business that allows employees to log on to their Office 365 accounts and sync, read, write, and create events in their Mail and Calendar services. The tools I have at my disposal are Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, and the .NET Framework. I've started a .NET Web Site project already, and at this point restarting as a MVC would cost too much in time and labor, but as absolute last resort we will.

I have signed up for a trial subscription of Azure (the least user friendly dashboard ever!), an Office 365 Developer account, a paid Office 365 account. I have registered my app in Application Registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) and the Outlook Dev Portal App Registration Tool (https://dev.outlook.com/AppRegistration) I've had more success from the Outlook Dev Portal App Registration Tool (I actually get some hints back from the server that a token was sent).

Some of my struggles can be seen this in this StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752049/active-directory-authentication-library-adal-wont-install-visual-studio-2013/36753397#36753397) My team ended up downloading the code (dotnet-tutorial.sln) in this tutorial's repository, but we couldn't even get it to work locally. The load bar would just sit and sit and sit for hours when we tried to Restore NuGet Packages, and the code wouldn't run in a browser because of 30 parser errors.

Okay, so how do I (in straightforward steps that work) get Mail and Calendar into my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard dependency on MVC, so that shouldn't be a problem. As Nan mentions in his answer, the [tutorial](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet) on dev.outlook.com is a step-by-step process that works. It does use MVC, but hopefully you can translate that into your non-MVC web app.

That tutorial uses the Azure v2 app model, which does not require you to create an Azure subscription or even an Office 365 subscription, since it works with Outlook.com!

If it's the libraries that are tripping you up, then take a look at this library-less sample: https://github.com/jasonjoh/dotnet-outlook-nosdk. It implements the OAuth and REST calls manually and sends them via HTTP.

Comment: Jason, I will try this in Visual Studio 2015. As I said to Nan, "Then in nuget package manager of the project , update the "Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices" dll to the newest version" this is where my loading bar just spins and spins for hours. (This is in VS 2013).

Comment: So I'm having some success with the SDK-less code sample. However, after logging in, I am redirected to the home/error page where it states, "Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Error: unsupported_response_type - The provided value for the input parameter 'response_type' is not allowed for this client. Expected value is 'code'." What could be the cause of this? I have events in my Calendar in the Office 365 portal.

Comment: I got the first screenshot from when I logged in the first time, and the second screenshot when I logged in the second time using my business O365 account [link](http://imgur.com/a/LezdP)

Comment: Those are both errors in the authentication portion. The error seems to indicate a problem with the app registration. Can you screenshot your app's registration on apps.dev.microsoft.com and post it?

Comment: I just got it to authenticate and log me in. I had to select "allow implicit flow" in the App Registration Portal. This is a great start - the first success of getting a tutorial to work in 20+ hours of trying.

Comment: Hmm. It shouldn't require implicit flow as per my understanding. However, I do see the same behavior as you. Let me ask the Azure auth folks to weigh in on this.

Comment: Ok, I got clarification from Azure. Essentially doing a `response_type=code+id_token` request is considered a "hybrid" flow (implicit + non-implicit), and Azure disables hybrid if you uncheck the "Allow implicit flow" checkbox. I've passed the feedback that this checkbox could be renamed or given some help tooltips to explain what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

Actually , [this document](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet) has provided detail explanation and steps for how to get O365 mail with a MVC web application . You are more likely want to know how to make [this code sample](https://github.com/jasonjoh/dotnet-tutorial) work so you could learn the code/api better . I would share you how i use that sample in my environment :

1. Head over to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com to quickly get a client ID and secret. Using the sign in buttons, sign in with either your Microsoft account (Outlook.com), or your work or school account (Office 365).The detail steps you could find in the "Implementing OAuth2" segment of the README.md.
2. Download the code in tutorial's repository or connect to the solution in GitHub directly from Visual Studio.
3. Open microsoft visual studio 2015, open the project (select .sln file).
4. When load the project , if you press F5 ,you will get parser error that can't find "Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices". Then in nuget package manager of the project , **update the "Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices" dll to the newest version** . Rebuild the project .
5. Open the web.config file ,add the following keys inside the element: `<add key="ida:ClientID" value="YOUR APP ID" /><add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="YOUR APP PASSWORD" />`
6. Press F5 to debug the application , enter your o365 account ,grant permissions:
   [image]
7. You will get your mail messages successfully .

You could find more Office 365 API code samples and videos form [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .

Comment: Hi Nan, Yes I have been following along with the two documents you linked to. On the fourth step that you detailed, "Then in nuget package manager of the project , update the "Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices" dll to the newest version" this is where my loading bar just spins and spins for hours. This is in VS 2013. I will try this all again in VS 2015 since I just installed it.